# XSLT How do I remove the <span> elements inside of the <p> element?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Assume that I have a document with paragraph blocks that look like this:

```
<p>
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself
transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like 
back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, 
slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was  
hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.  
<span style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255); color:rgb(102, 102, 102)">
    <span next="added-diff-1" changeId="added-diff-0" previous="first-diff" id="added-diff-0" class="diff-html-added">
    Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.
    </span>
</span>
His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked.
</p>
```

Is it possible to use XSLT to read the *p* element but exclude the *span* tags and the content between the span tags that is nested inside of the paragraph? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity transformation template plus the template `<xsl:template match="p//span"/>`.